# Postgresql JSONB inline sum of array values

Tags: postgresql, sum, jsonb

I am trying to figure out what the query syntax is for an inline sum for a specific field in an object array. My data is structured like this

```
CREATE TABLE "orders" (
  order_id int8,
  tax_lines jsonb
);
INSERT INTO "orders"(order_id, tax_lines) VALUES (4521745668, '[
  {
    "rate": 0.029,
    "price": "0.43",
    "title": "CO State Tax"
  },
  {
    "rate": 0.00985,
    "price": "0.15",
    "title": "Boulder County Tax"
  },
  {
    "rate": 0.0496,
    "price": "0.74",
    "title": "Boulder Municipal Tax"
  }
]');
```

The result i am trying to achieve is

```
order_id         cumulative_tax_rate
4521745668       .08845
```

This is as far as i have gotten

```
SELECT
  o.order_id,
  SUM((jsonb_array_elements(o.tax_lines) ->> 'rate')::numeric) AS cumulative_tax_rate
 FROM orders o WHERE o.order_id = '4521745668'
```

but it keeps asking for a GROUP BY clause which I would like to avoid. I was wondering if it is possible to perform this aggregation at the row level without a group by clause and, if so, what that syntax might look like?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it a typo `INSERT INTO >>>> "MY_TABLE" <<<<` ?

Comment: indeed it was, thank you for pointing that out. Edited and fixed.

Comment: `shopify_order_id` and `jsondata` aren't in your `orders` table

Comment: What is your postgresql version ?

Comment: It shouldn't ask for a GROUP BY statement. It should throw an error on a nonexistent column. What code are you *actually* trying to execute?

Comment: Select statement has been fixed. Running Postgres 9.6.

Comment: Why you want to avoid the group by?

Comment: you need aggregation, not for that one row, but for three array elements in json. check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you said you want to avoid the `group by` I will provide a solution with it because it is what you indeed need.

```
select order_id, 
       sum(tax) tax
  from (SELECT o.order_id, 
               (jsonb_array_elements(o.tax_lines)->>'rate')::numeric tax
          FROM orders o) a
 where order_id = 4521745668 -- this you add if you want a specific order id
  group by order_id;         -- without it you will have all orders tax sum
```

This will give you the result you want:

```
  order_id      tax
 4521745668   0.08845
```

And if you need just add the where clause for that `order_id` in the outer query. `where order_id = 4521745668` no need for quotes since it is a int8 value.

Comment: How would you generate all rows' tax and order_id without summing them all up?

Comment: @foureyedraven well, just use the subquery instead.

Answer (score 1):

I aggregate with window, not group by  - is it what you are looking for?..

```
t=# with a as (
SELECT
  o.order_id,
 (jsonb_array_elements(o.tax_lines ) ->> 'rate')::float AS cumulative_tax_rate
  FROM orders o WHERE order_id = 4521745668
)
select
distinct order_id, sum(cumulative_tax_rate) over (partition by order_id)
from a;
  order_id  |   sum
------------+---------
 4521745668 | 0.08845
(1 row)
```